# generating unique ordered non duplicate combinations in java for a list of list

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations

I know there are many similar questions, and I have read them for hours. But none of them seems to meet my requirement.

I have list of list ( list< list < string > >) the lists can be of any size.

Example:

My outer  list size is: 4

contents of the list

```
 1. list(0) a,b,c            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; size:3

 2. list(1) d,b,f,m          &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; size:4

 3. list(2) x,a              &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  size:2

 4. list(3) b,e,d,m,a        &nbsp; &nbsp; size:5
```

Here my combinations will be

```
adxb

adxe 

adxd (adx) duplicate element will be removed after generating combination

adxm

adxa (adx)  

adab (adb)

adae (ade)

...
```

...so on

I have to generate combinations by picking one element from each list
 combination length will be max of 4 (size of the outer list),sometimes it will be shrinked if i get same elements in the combination

my number of combinations will be **product of number of elements in each inner list.**

Here in the above example number of combinations will be `3x4x2x5=120` combinations

As my list contains duplicate elements i will get duplicate combinations as well
here if i have **adab adba** then **adba** is a duplicate as **order doesn't matter**.

The problem is i use straightforward approach to generate combinations, if my outer list size grows and my inner list contains more elements , i end up generating combinations in millions but only 1000 or 2000 will be unique rest all duplicates.

Is there any algorithmic approach to generate only unique combinations instead of generating all combinations?

Comment: accumulative set product of all-domain-sets-union can create all possible combinations, and with no duplicates

Answer (score 1):

1: Is this homework?
2: How many lists do you anticipate using as a maximum?

Basically... there's not going to be some sort of magical way to do this... you're going to have to check to see if the string you're building already contains the letter you're considering adding, and that's what you want to optimize -- checking if your String already contains a letter.

If you're doing this for homework, I think you can use a String.contains( 'a' ) || String.contains( 'A' ) to see if the String already contains a certain letter ('a' in this case).  I'll leave the rest of it to you.  Note that this is an O(n^2) operation.

If you're doing this for a more... industrial... application, then I see another option.

If you're going to have a large number of String lists, then you'll probably want to use a TreeSet to store a list of characters you've already used.  For example, after going through the first list (a, b, c), you'll see if the TreeSet of "used characters" contains an "a", and if not you will add "a" to the String you're building and also add "a" to the TreeSet of used characters.  You will then go to the second list, and see if your TreeSet contains a letter d, and so forth.  Overall, this will be an o(n*log(n)) function.

The benefit of using a TreeSet to store a list of "used" characters, is that it costs o(log(n)) to add and check for characters as opposed to o(n) to check for characters in a String using String.contains("a").  (You can even convert all to lowercase before adding/checking.)

The down-side to using a TreeSet, is that there's a moderate amount of overhead in just instantiating a TreeSet, and it might not be worth it if you're only using small lists of string lists.

---

Question:  Why do you have a list of lists of Strings, as opposed to a list of lists of characters?  Seems like a list of lists of characters would be more appropriate.

---

If you're not familiar with what I mean by o(n^2), o(log(n)) or o(n), then o(whatever) is just a notation for approximating how the running time of a function expands with the number of arguments passed to that function.
-For example, if you run an o(n^2) function with 4 arguments, it will take 4^2 == 16 time (where "time" is an arbitrary time unit).  If you run it with 8 arguments, it will take 8^2 == 64 time.  It increases quadratically as your input size increases.
-For example, if you run an o(n) function with 4 arguments, it will 4 time.  If you run an o(n) function with 8 arguments, it will take 8 time.
-For example, if you run an o(log(n)) function with 4 arguments, it will take 2 time.  If you run an o(log(n)) function with 8 arguments, it will take 3 time.  (Assuming log is base two.)

Hopefully you get the idea -- the point is that the difference between o(n^2), o(n*log(n)), o(n), and o(log(n)) is minor with small numbers, but as soon as you start getting lists of size 100 or more, it's going to be significant -- o(n^2) will take 10,000 time and o(n*log(n)) will take something like 670 time -- that is, it will be 15 times faster at only 100 lists.  At 1,000 lists it will be 100 times faster.

Comment: thanks for the reply. 
Actually it's a list of objects(domain class representing a table) which have more contents.it's a business requirement and confidential one, so i used alphabets and quoted as List < List < String> > instead of List < List <DomainClass> >. I anticipate maximum of 20 inner lists , but each inner list can be of size 30 max.. .. the problem is when i get bigger list's it takes 2 to 5 minutes to process List< List<Domain>>, i may get upto 20000 List< List < DomainObjects> >. so it takes more than 100 hrs to complete. need logic to process in 3 to 4 hours

Comment: Hrrrrmmm.  I had an idea while I was at work today.  If you have 20 inner lists, I think I know of a way to make it run 19x faster (as compared to just naively iterating through all 20 inner lists) with a recursive algorithm.  Additionally, use of a TreeSet will probably make it run 2x faster.  Lastly, my experience with multithreading stuff like this on my Intel i7 930 shows that you can make stuff run 5x faster(ish) -- although you're going to be using almost all of your CPU's capacity.  So... hopefully we can cut your time by a bit.  Wait for a second post with the recursive idea.

Comment: You know what... I should have known better.  This problem is NP-hard.  Running on 10 inner lists of size 5 takes ~5.6 seconds, but jump it up to 11 and it takes 28 seconds.  12 inner lists takes 137 seconds.  (It kind of increases by 5 times for every inner list you add, which makes sense, since each inner list has 5 characters.)

Answer (score 0):

I totally struck-out.  Problem is NP-hard.  Recommend you find a different way to do whatever it is that you want to do.

Edit: Just re-read your original post.  Seems like you edited it after I read it last night...  I now see that you're not asking for the below algorithm, but for something else.  =/  Will think about it, but likely won't come up with anything.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    long runningTime = 0;
    int numTrials = 1;

    for( int i = 0; i < numTrials; i++ )
    {
        List<List<String>> theLists = UniqueStringTest.makeListOfLists(12, 5);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        RecursiveAnalyzer ra = new RecursiveAnalyzer( theLists );
        ra.run();
        runningTime += ( System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime );

    }

    System.out.println( "Finished " + numTrials + " trials in " + 
                        runningTime + " milliseconds." );

}

public static class RecursiveAnalyzer implements Runnable
{

    private List<List<String>> theLists;
    private Stack<String> buildingString;
    private TreeSet<String> usedChars;

    public RecursiveAnalyzer( List<List<String>> newTheLists )
    {
        this.theLists = newTheLists;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        this.usedChars = new TreeSet<>();
        this.buildingString = new Stack<>();

        recursiveAnalysisHelper( 0 );
    }

    protected void recursiveAnalysisHelper( int currentDepth )
    {
        List<String> currentList = this.theLists.get( currentDepth );
        boolean haveOneOnStack = false;

        //Iterate over each character in list number currentDepth
        for( int i = 0; i < currentList.size(); i++ )
        {
            if ( this.usedChars.contains( currentList.get(i) ) == false )
            {
                this.usedChars.add( currentList.get(i) );
                this.buildingString.push( currentList.get(i) );
                haveOneOnStack = true;
            }
            else
            {
                haveOneOnStack = false;
            }

            if ( (currentDepth+1) < this.theLists.size() )
            {
                recursiveAnalysisHelper( currentDepth+1 );
            }
            else
            {
                String answer = "";
                for( String s : this.buildingString )
                {
                    answer += s;
                }
                //System.out.println(answer);
            }

            if( haveOneOnStack == true )
            {
                this.buildingString.pop();
                this.usedChars.remove( currentList.get(i) );
            }

        }

    }
}

public static List<List<String>> makeListOfLists( int numLists, int numChars )
{
    List<List<String>> answer = new ArrayList<>();
    Random rand = new Random();
    if ( numChars > 25 )
    {
        numChars = 25;
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < numLists; i++ )
    {
        List<String> anInnerList = new ArrayList<>();
        for( int j = 0; j < numChars; )
        {
            //Makes a lowercase letter
            String aChar = Character.toString((char)(rand.nextInt(26)+97));
            if ( anInnerList.contains( aChar ) == false )
            {
                anInnerList.add( aChar );
                j++;
            }
        }
        answer.add(anInnerList);
    }

    return answer;
}
```